# For TTS, do I use BingSpeech or TranslatorSpeech?

Tags: java, text-to-speech, bing, microsoft-translator

For a year, I have been using Azure Marketplace for Dutch text-to-speech. That will end in April.

I have new Azure Cognitive Services accounts for TranslatorText, TranslatorSpeech and BingSpeech. I have BingSpeech working (in Java, GitHub TTS sample) but it does not support Dutch TTS (12 other languages). But BingSpeech Speech Recognition supports Dutch (and 20 other languages). TranslatorSpeech supports 60 languages, including Dutch and apparently does both Speech Recognition and TTS. But I cannot find a Java TranslatorSpeech that will work for TTS, and I can't seem to be able to modify the Java I have for Azure Marketplace to work with TranslatorSpeech.

Could someone give me guidance as to how to proceed to get Dutch TTS? Any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: Look for the MRCP protocol. It's a standard for TTS and Speech Recognition. You will find many libraries in all languages.

Comment: Thanks Guillaume. I had a good look at the MRCP protocol. I don't believe there are any libraries that add Dutch to BingSpeech. I really need someone from Microsoft to answer the simple question as to how I get Dutch (which I get wonderfully on Marketplace) in Azure Cognitive Services. Is BingSpeech the only TTS game after Marketplace shuts down? Am I doomed to lose Dutch TTS? Simple questions I would think for Microsoft staff to answer.

Comment: I'd appreciate any kind of an answer.

Comment: With a bit of help from Microsoft, I have managed to get my Java TTS software working with BingSpeech in Dutch. Unfortunately, at the moment, BingSpeech has only a relatively lower quality Dutch female voice and not the much better Dutch male voice that I use in the old Marketplace TTS. So my question remains: Should I be using BingSpeech of TranslatorSpeech (which may have the male voice. I don't know)?